# Конвертация простых типов в Ардуино.Не пойму

Tags: arduino

Есть экран Nextion. Необходимо изменять в поле числа программно. Экран предоставляет такие возможности Числа берутся из файла. Изменения происходит так:

```
Nextion.setComponentValue("componentName", int value);
```

Из файла читаю число

```
int rf = myFile.read(); //Число 100. В файле
Nextion.setComponentValue("component",rf);
```

Но в компонент выводится число 10. Но, если выводить в консоль

```
Serial.write(rf);
```

то выводит как раз 100. А если сделать вывод

```
Serial.print(rf);
```

то выводит 4948481310. Что и объясняет откуда берется 10 в компоненте. 
Если сделать вывод с явным приведением типа

```
Serial.print((char)rf);
```

То выводит 100, но в экран снова записывает 10.
В общем как и в что конвертировать, что бы при выводе в компонент получать 100? Спасибо за внимание.

Попробовал вот так:

```
char al[10]; 
al[count] = myFile.read();
Nextion.setComponentText(arrayComponent[count],String(al));
Serial.print(al[count]);
```

Вот что получается. Serial.print выводит как надо. А вот текст в компоненте меняется на содержимое массива. Ну это понятно. Логично изменить String(al) на String(al[count]). Но не в этом случае. Если изменить, то скажем при чтении числа 789, названия в трех компонентах меняются на 7,8,9. Т.е в компоненте 1 текст становиться 7,в компоненте 2 текст становиться 8 и т.д. Но оно и понятно. Массив то как символьный объявлен. И вот тут то и затык. Если объявить как строковый то начинает выводит непонятный набор цифр о чём писал выше. Nextion.setComponentValue может принимать только строки. И как вот быть в такой ситуации? Второй день пошёл как не могу ничего придумать.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вопроса нашёл и использовал библиотеку Arduino FAT16/FAT32 Library. Она намного функциональнее. И главное, в ней реализована функция fgets и getline которых мне и не хватало. Всем спасибо за внимание.